# Getting 'Any(ComputeError("Aggregation did not return a Series"))'

Tags: python, python-polars

I am getting the error "Getting 'Any(ComputeError("Aggregation did not return a Series"))'." while running the below query in production using Dynamo as the DB. So I am getting data from dynamo which is then converted into Polars dataframe on which query is run.

Now when I am using the same data and converting it into csv and then using it to run my query locally it is running fine.

Query:

```
 averageInspectionScorePercentage = df_polars.groupby(
            "ReportId"
        ).agg(
            [
                pl.col("AchievedPercentage")
                .mean()
                .round(2)
                .alias("AchievedPercentage"),
                pl.col("AuditTargetScore")
                .mean()
                .round(2)
                .alias("AuditTargetScore"),
                pl.col("ReportedInMonth").unique().alias("reportedInMonth"),
                pl.col("ReportedInYear").unique().alias("ReportedInYear")
            ]
        )
```

Sample data:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1rh1.png)

Output:

```
[2021-12-06 13:55:10,346: WARNING/MainProcess] shape: (2, 5)
┌───────────────────────┬────────────────────┬──────────────────┬─────────────────┬────────────────┐
│ ReportId              ┆ AchievedPercentage ┆ AuditTargetScore ┆ reportedInMonth ┆ ReportedInYear │
│ ---                   ┆ ---                ┆ ---              ┆ ---             ┆ ---            │
│ str                   ┆ f64                ┆ f64              ┆ str             ┆ i64            │
╞═══════════════════════╪════════════════════╪══════════════════╪═════════════════╪════════════════╡
│ f582a04f20a046969ca92 ┆ 100                ┆ 80               ┆ December        ┆ 2021           │
│ 6c563f391db           ┆                    ┆                  ┆                 ┆                │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b2a738c6f9334b0fb0713a
  31756bc900            ┆ 80.                ┆ 80               ┆ December        ┆ 2021           │
│                       ┆                    ┆                  ┆                 ┆                │
```

Above is the desired output when I run the query on csv converting the csv into polars dataframe from the same dynamo data. I have checked data types as well. I am unable to understand what might be the reason for the above error. I have exhausted all my options. Any suggestions are appreciated. Just need a direction to go in.

Comment: Which version do you run in production? Have you tried the latest version?

Comment: We are currently using 0.10.26.

Comment: Do you see any difference, if you don't round after the mean?